# C# работа с dbf файлами

Tags: c#, импорт, dbf

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from " + dbfFileName, oleDbConn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
```

На последней команде вот такая ошибка:

> Запись удалена.
>   Ключ поиска не найден ни в одной записи.

Параметры dbf файла:
Тип dBase III+
Index file No

Строка подключения:

```
@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + SetupProgram.PathToDBFFile +
";Extended Properties=dBase III"
```

Comment: Мммм... дай бог памяти... обычно в таких случаях помогает сжать и восстановить базу данных, а вообще подобные ошибки могут быть по весьма разным поводам. PS Шёл 2017 год... мыши плакали, кололись, но продолжали работать с dbf... )) Последний раз работал с dbf в девяностых годах, думал, уже на предприятиях ушли на более современные базы.

Comment: Как раз задача и состоит в уходе от dbf. Это кусок кода импорта из dbf в sql. Странно, но на другом компе данная ошибка не возникает